# VSC does not choose anaconda env

Tags: python, version-control, anaconda, conda

I installed VCS and Anaconda and I created an env using conda, but VCS does not seem to be using it, no matter what I do.

How do I get VCS to use the right env?

First, when I run "code" it seems to not even use any env. Honestly, I am not sure if it is even using an env.

I am using the "run file" option because at least it activates conda first, but it does not activate the right env, instead it always runs with "conda activate base"

I see that in the right bottom, you can choose the right version of python and that works, but it does not activate the selected env.

So how do I select a condo env in my workspace or in general?

Environment:
OS: Windows 11
VS Code 1.79.2
conda 23.3.1
Python 3.10

```
base                     C:\Users\user\anaconda3
pytorch               *  C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\pytorch
test                     C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\test
```

I am trying to use the pytorch env, but VCS always uses the base.